# Variable amount of checkboxes (GUI matlab)

Tags: matlab, user-interface, checkbox, listbox

I have in my programmatic GUI the following listbox:

```
    h.listbox = uicontrol('style','listbox','units','pixels',...
                          'position',[10,175,200,200],...
                          'string',components_index);
```

This gives me an output containing a row of stocks in a listbox.

What I now want, is that in front of every stock, I have a checkbox. Keep in mind that the amount of stocks is variable.

Can anyone point towards a solution?

Thanks in advance,

Jonathan

**_______________________________________________________________**--

After the help I've come up with the following:

Thanks, that's what I'm looking for. I have just one little problem now. I made the code for the uitable:

```
h.table = uitable('units', 'pixels', 'position', [10, 100, 200, 200], ...
                     'columnname', {'Yes/No'},...
                     'columnformat',{'logical'},...
                     'ColumnEditable', true,...
                     'rowname',components_index);
```

But I can't click on my textboxes. They all appear as they should, but can't change their value.

Comment: A [`uitable`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitable.html) with the appropriate [column settings](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitableproperties.html#brglhyc) might be a more appropriate GUI object to use.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question if you would have time to look at it, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining the Data field (e.g., populating the checkbox column with `false`):

```
components_index = {'one1','two2','three3'};
h.table = uitable('units', 'pixels', 'position', [10, 100, 200, 200], ...
                         'columnname', {'Yes/No'},...
                         'columnformat',{'logical'},...
                         'ColumnEditable', true,...
                         'rowname',components_index,...
                         'data',false(numel(components_index),1));
```